# Application crashing on rotating screen after implementing search

Tags: android

```
I have a list fragment which I am adding on create of activity. I have a search functionality which performs search on text change. I don't have a problem when I try to rotate the complete list fragment but when I try to rotate after searching i.e, after I perform filter on the cursor and try to rotate the screen the application crashes. 

My logCat

11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {osm.droid.mat/osm.droid.mat.Accounts}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2610)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2638)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3547)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4856)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getCount(CursorWrapper.java:57)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at osm.droid.fragments.FilterCursorWrapper.<init>(FilterCursorWrapper.java:21)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at osm.droid.fragments.FragmentDisplay.SetAccounts(FragmentDisplay.java:138)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at osm.droid.fragments.FragmentDisplay.access$2(FragmentDisplay.java:121)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at osm.droid.fragments.FragmentDisplay$1.onQueryTextChange(FragmentDisplay.java:173)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.SearchView.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1192)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.SearchView.access$1900(SearchView.java:93)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.SearchView$11.onTextChanged(SearchView.java:1691)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7398)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3730)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3585)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:95)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3560)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3460)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12012)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11990)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.restoreActionViewStates(MenuBuilder.java:358)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:477)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:833)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu(Activity.java:2634)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatHoneycomb.invalidateOptionsMenu(ActivityCompatHoneycomb.java:29)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(FragmentActivity.java:633)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:781)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at osm.droid.fragments.FragmentDisplay.onCreateView(FragmentDisplay.java:38)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:439)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1199)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5121)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
11-11 18:03:09.929: E/AndroidRuntime(24053):    ... 13 more
11-11 18:03:34.092: I/Process(24053): Sending signal. PID: 24053 SIG: 9
11-11 18:03:34.643: W/ResourceType(24750): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
11-11 18:03:34.653: W/ResourceType(24750): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

My list fragment code. When I am trying to rotate the screen onDestroy is being called twice. So the cursor is becoming null. I don't want that to happen. 
I know I can use android:configChanges but I knew from previous answers that this is not a good approach. Can I find a better solution?

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_list,container, false);
         //Loading the list view
         listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         setHasOptionsMenu(true);       
         return rootView;
    }
    public FragmentDisplay()
    {
        super();
    }
    public FragmentDisplay(Cursor cursor)
    {
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }
    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.accounts, menu); 
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
        //Attaching query listener to search icon
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        SetAccounts(null);
        //On click of list view item
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int id,
                long idInTable) 
            {
                OpenNewAppointment(id);
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Searching for: " +id+"  Id" +idInTable+ "...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

          });

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
    /*** Creating intent to open new appointment 
     * We will be using the id of the selected item in list view.
     * This method is used to create a new Create Appointment activity and also to send the result back to Create Appointment.
     * @param id
     */
   public void OpenNewAppointment(int id)
   {
       Intent intent =new Intent(mActivity,CreateAppointment.class);
       String accountName=null;
       String crmId=null;

       cursor.moveToPosition(id);
       accountName = (cursor.getString(8));
       crmId = (cursor.getString(0));

       intent.putExtra(Account_Name,new String[] {accountName, crmId});
           if(CreateAppointment.NewActivity)
           {
               //Starts new create appointment activity
               startActivity(intent);
           }
           else
           {
               //Sends the result back to create appointment
               getActivity().setResult(CreateAppointment.RESULT_ACCOUNT,intent);
               getActivity().finish();
           }
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /***Set adapter according to the requirement
     * All the records can be loaded into adapter or filtered accounts can be loaded
     * @param strQuery
     */
    private void SetAccounts(String strQuery)
    {
        DbConnection db = null;
        if(strQuery == null)
        {           
            if(cursor == null)
            {
                //If cursor is null database call is made
                db = new DbConnection(mActivity);
                cursor = db.SelectRecords(CRMAccountDbOperations.getTableName(), CRMAccountDbOperations.getColoumnNames(),null,null,null,null,"Name COLLATE NOCASE ASC",null);
            }
            mAdapter = new AdapterClass(cursor, mActivity);

        }
        else if(strQuery != "")
        {
            //Accounts filtered according to the text entered are loaded.
            fwc = new FilterCursorWrapper(cursor, strQuery,8);
            mAdapter = new AdapterClass(fwc, mActivity);
        }   
        else
        {
            mAdapter = new AdapterClass(cursor, mActivity);
        }
        //Set list view and adapter
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        if(db != null)
        {
            db.CloseDatabase();
        }
    }

    private String currentQuery = null;

    /*** Filtering on text change
     * This method is called every time the text in search text box is changed.
     */
    final private OnQueryTextListener queryListener = new OnQueryTextListener() 
    {       
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("List");               
                    currentQuery = "";
                } 
                else 
                {
                    getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("List - Searching for: " + newText);
                    currentQuery = newText;

                }   
                SetAccounts(currentQuery);

                return false;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {            
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("List");               
                currentQuery = "";
            }
            else {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle("List - Searching for: " + query);
                currentQuery = query;

            }   
            //SetAccounts(currentQuery);
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code and logcat output?

Comment: Did you provide an id for that view? In both variants of the layout?

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I gave it an id in layout.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
if(cursor == null)
        {
            //If cursor is null database call is made
            db = new DbConnection(mActivity);
            cursor = db.SelectRecords(CRMAccountDbOperations.getTableName(), CRMAccountDbOperations.getColoumnNames(),null,null,null,null,"Name COLLATE NOCASE ASC",null);
        }
```

to the start of the `SetAccounts` method so that cursor is available in all the conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.When I try to debug the code and try to rotate the screen SaveAccounts() is being called on onCreate and the cursor is being loaded and then filtered then after that onDestroy is being called again. So my cursor becomes null because onDestroy is called again.

Comment: Can you check if `OpenNewAppointment` is being called on orientation change?

Comment: Yes it is being called.

Comment: Maybe it is calling `getActivity().finish();` there